# killerweather : is it possible to launch multipler kafka stream with akka?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming

I created an application based on the example of killerweather.
I want to create 5 kafkastream (with differents topics and differents raws)

First question , is it better to use one application by kafkastream or create 1 application with multiple kafkastream (one by akka actor)?

I tried one application with all kafka stream in. But i ve this error : Could not compute split, block input-11-1480936985200 not found.
Do you know why? 
my storage level is : StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2 for each stream.

Thanks a lot

Thomas

Comment: It the tag "apache-kafka-streams" correct? It the question related to this library?

Comment: Indeed, it was an error :) i removed it. Thanks Matthias